# How to create record with the same id as a parent record from a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a system where a teacher can create a lesson, and the student inputs an answer. I have a table cycling through each lesson like this:

```
<h1>Listing Courses</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @learns.each do |learn| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to learn.title, new_lesson_path %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Learn', new_learn_path %>
```

What I need is a way to create a new model record (the new model is `Lesson`, the old one is `Learn`) that has a `user_id`(already figured out) and a `learn_id`(the one in question). Does anyone know how to give the `lesson_id` the value of the lesson that was clicked on?

Sorry if this was confusing, and thanks :)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Add the relations of lear lesson and user. Is user_id a reference to the student or the teacher? 
Is the lesson created by the student when he click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters in urls:

```
new_lesson_path(learn_id: learn.id)
```

and then get it from `params[:learn_id]` in controller's `new` action

The more elegant way is to use a nested resource.

```
resources :learns do
  resources :lessons, shallow:true
end
```

so that your url will be like `/learns/123/lessons/new`, helper like `new_learn_lesson_path(learn)` and still `:learn_id` in params

Comment: Works! One thing though, how would I make a form for the lesson?

Comment: @Xavier the same way you usually do, but it will be like `form_for [@learn, @lesson] do ...`

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate it!